# java Date format convert 'M/d/yyyy' to 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX' like 2021-04-05T00:00-07:00[UTC-07:00]

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8

Expected output : `2021-04-05T00:00-07:00[UTC-07:00]`

```
String sDate1="05/04/2021";
Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy").parse(sDate1);

SimpleDateFormat sdf;
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
String text = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println("sdf:      "+text);
ZonedDateTime d = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(),
                                          ZoneId.systemDefault());

ZonedDateTime zdt= ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
System.out.println("zdt:     "+  d);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
ZonedDateTime result = ZonedDateTime.parse(""+d, formatter);
System.out.println("zdt result ::   "+result);
```

output :

```
sdf:      2021-04-05T00:00:00.000+05:30

zdt:     2021-04-05T00:00+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]

zdt result ::   2021-04-05T00:00+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]
```

But Expected out is in this format `2021-04-05T00:00-07:00[UTC-07:00]`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. You are already using `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Stick to that API and avoid unnecessary conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `OffsetDateTime` and the appropriate [formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to output it like you want `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXX'['OOOO']'"`

- `O` for *localized zone-offset*, and `OOOO` for the `UTC-08:00` style
- `X` for *zone-offset* and `XXX` for the `-08:30` style
- `Locale.FRENCH` to show `UTC` and not `GMT`, don't really know why here :/

```
String sDate1 = "05/04/2021";

DateTimeFormatter inFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter outFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXX'['OOOO']'");

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDate.parse(sDate1, inFormatter).atTime(0, 0);

OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-7));
String result = odt.format(outFormatter);
System.out.println(result); // 2021-04-05T00:00-07:00[UTC-07:00]

ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-7)));
result = zdt.format(outFormatter);
System.out.println(result); // 2021-04-05T00:00-07:00[UTC-07:00]
```

Comment: I have a little question, why the output is `2021-04-05T00:00-07:00[GMT-07:00]`, not `2021-04-05T00:00-07:00[UTC-07:00]`. What is the difference between UTC and GMT？

Comment: actually required UTC instead of GMT

Comment: @Holinc You have GMT showing up ? You don't have the expect output shown on last line of my answer ? Because this is what I have

Comment: @azro Yes, I am getting output  like this  "2021-04-05T00:00-07:00[GMT-07:00]"

Comment: @GSriHAri Adding `Locale.FRENCH` seems to fix but I don't know why, look my edit to see it

Comment: it is working with  ZonedDateTime  instead of OffsetDateTime.
ZonedDateTime dt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-7)));           Thanks @azro

Comment: @GSriHAri You can think about accepting the answer so, the green tick on left :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot easier than you think.

```
    String sDate1="05/04/2021";
    ZonedDateTime result = LocalDate.parse(sDate1, DATE_FORMATTER)
            .atStartOfDay(DESIRED_ZONE);
    System.out.println("zdt result ::   " + result);
```

The constants used are declared:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
private static final ZoneId DESIRED_ZONE = ZoneId.of("UTC-07:00");
```

And the output is the expected:

> zdt result ::   2021-04-05T00:00-07:00[UTC-07:00]

Caveats: I understood that you required a time zone of `UTC-07:00`. This isn’t a real time zone, it’s just a made-up zone ID for a UTC offset. A real time zone ID is like `America/Vancouver` or `America/Phoenix`, so *region/city* format. For most purposes, for a date and time with just a UTC offset we should prefer an `OffsetDateTime` over a `ZonedDateTime` as in the other answer.